# Connect 2 DVI monitors via Mini DisplayPort?

Tags: multiple-monitors, dvi, mini-displayport

I have a macbook pro with a Mini DisplayPort video out. I want to connect it to two dell monitors that have a DVI input. Can this be done?

I brought the monitors with a dell PC. For the PC I used this splitter to attach both monitors to a single output. If the Mini DisplayPort can't split into 2 DVI signals, can It be converted to this splitter?

[image]

My monitors also have a VGA input. Can a Mini DisplayPort be connected to two VGA monitors? I know that the quality wont be as good with VGA as DVI.

Comment: Which version MacBook Pro do you have?  Is it a standard miniDP, or the new lightning bolt variety?  Is there an hdmi out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That splitter uses a proprietary connection to a Dell video card.  As far as I know, it only works with Dell computers that support dual monitors.  I don't think there's any way to split a single Mini-DisplayPort signal out to two monitors, certainly not to provide dual monitor functionality.

Not to say this couldn't be done with the Thunderbolt standard (which actually uses the same connector as Mini-DP) and the right device/drivers, but as is, the Mini-DisplayPort port is meant to output one video signal to one display.

Nice hands by the way.

Comment: That's not a proprietary connection on the single side . . . it's [DMS-59](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59).  You actually see DMS-59 pretty frequently on small form factors, e.g. 1U servers.

Comment: @ernie, thanks for the connector ID help.  Had never seen it anywhere other than Dell machines.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am having a brain fart here, but I don't recognize that output on your splitter, so I can't tell you if that can be used, but you can easily find a DVI-I Dual Link Y splitter on newegg.com or amazon. With one of those you can buy an apple [mini display to dvi](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB570Z/B/mini-displayport-to-dvi-adapter) and everything should be kosher.

**EDIT**

What your splitter outputs to is [DMS-59](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59) which isn't supported by apple's adapter. You will have to buy a new splitter that goes from two DVI-I dual channel to DVI-D dual channel.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like [this](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_se/?productTabs=1#specs).

Also, you probably won't see that much of a difference if you used VGA instead of DVI. But on the other hand, why choose a Analog signal which is more sensitive when it comes to cabel length and noise, when you have a digital signal to use :)

**UPDATE**
I know it doesn't say Mac under supported operating systems, but look [here](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/support/compatibility/gxm/home/), it looks like it is still supported with their devices, so you might find another device with your needs.

Comment: From the product description:  "Supported Operating Systems:  Microsoft® Windows® 8 (32/64bit), Windows 7 (32/64bit), Windows Vista® (32/64bit), Windows XP (32/64bit), Windows Server® 2012 (32/64bit), Windows Server 2003/2008 (32/64bit) and Linux®".  Don't see Mac.  Interesting device though, but I wonder how, and how well, it actually works.

Comment: Oh yea, damn...I guess I was alittle bit too quick their, but wierd it supports everything but MAC

Comment: @trpt4him check my update

Answer (score 0):

That splitter won't work because the input is a proprietary dell connector. I just tried this with a cheap $7 DVI splitter ([http://www.amazon.com/Cables-Unlimited-PCM-2260-DVI-D-Splitter/dp/B000H09RFM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000H09RFM)).  The result is both external monitors mirror the same screen (not helpful).  As far as I know, you must buy a USB to DVI converter for your second monitor.

Comment: Please be more specific. Which cheap splitter works?

Answer (score 0):

The D shaped female connector on your Dell PC is called DMS-59, or Dual Monitor Solution -59 pin.  Although it is not a proprietary Dell solution, it is specifically designed to support two monitors from a single DMS-59 output on a half-height video card.  A full height video card could fit two of these connectors, allowing connection of a total of four DVI monitors.

To my knowledge, there is no way to connect DisplayPort or Mini DisplayPort to more than one monitor.  If such a thing even exists, it's more than likely going to be more expensive than the alternative, which is to purchase a USB to DVI adapter dongle to supply the second monitor signal previously mentioned by others in this thread.